# WI-FI interface displayed as "device not ready" in nm-applet

Tags: wifi, pi-4, lxde, pixel, networkmanager

I'm using the Raspberry Pi 4B with 2GB of RAM. I have no problems with WIFI connection, though. But I can't make connection using `nm-applet` (and `nm-connection-editor`). On `nm-applet` it shows "device not ready" under "Wi-Fi Networks". Anyway, I can connect to WIFI using the built-in (LXDE or PIXEL, I believe) WIFI manager.

Summarising, I'd like to have possibility to connect to WIFI on wlan0 (Raspberry Pi 4B built-in WIFI interface) using NetworkManager.

Comment: Have you installed Network Manager?

Comment: @Milliways Yes, I installed "network-manager" and "network-manager-gnome"

Comment: What operating system do you use? Raspbian Buster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `Network Manager` you need to disable the default Raspbian `dhcpcd` network management tool. The 2 systems are incompatible.

There is no advantage in `Network Manager`, and it does not really suit the Pi modus operandi - in particular swapping SD Cards between Pi won't work - each Pi needs to be configured individually (although I cannot be sure what `Network Manager` would do on Raspbian).

You will probably have to enable [predictable network interface names](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#new-interface-names)